# How to calculate mean for previous 7 days with in same time

Tags: r

Hi I have data frame as below

In the below df how can we replace/find NA's in "Output" column which gives average for last 7 days with same time. Eg: If value for 2014-02-08 00:45 having NA then we need to replace with previous 7 average value i.e mean of values in from (feb 1 to feb 7) with same time(00:45)

```
dates = c('21-01-2014 00:15', '21-01-2014 00:30','21-01-2014 00:45','22-01-2014 00:00','22-01-2014 00:30','22-01-2014 00:45','23-01-2014 00:00','23-01-2014 00:15','23-01-2014 00:45','25-01-2014 00:45','26-01-2014 00:45','26-01-2014 00:46','26-01-2014 00:30','27-02-2014 00:45','28-02-2014 00:45','29-03-2014 00:45','30-03-2014 00:00','30-03-2014 00:45','30-03-2014 00:45','31-03-2014 00:45','01-04-2014 00:45','02-04-2014 00:45','03-04-2014 00:45')
value = c(20,   5,  10, 23, NA, 22, 12, 10, NA, 12, NA, 4,  19, 12, 
          NA,   NA, 2,  2,  NA, 14, NA, 21, NA)
output =c(20,   5,  10, 23, 5,  22, 12, 10, 10, 12, 11, 4,  19, 12,
          14,   14, 2,  2,  11.6,   14, 12, 21, 13.28)

df=data.frame(dates, value,output)

    df$dates = as.POSIXct(strptime(df$dates, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M","GMT"))
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you please structure your question better (punctuation)? I am not sure what you would like to do.

Comment: Do you want average value from previous 7 days or previous 7 records present in df? In your example you say 7 days (e.g. Feb 1 to Feb 7) but your desired output shows 14 on 2014-02-28, while there is only one record in the previous 7 days and it's value is 12.

Comment: Hi previous 7 days irrespective of week ,i.e if we have 5 days value in week then it should to previous to previous week for 2 days

Comment: Here is my desired output c(20, 5, 10, 23, 5, 22, 12, 10, 16, 12, 14.66, 4, 19, 12, 14, 14, 2, 2, 11.6, 14, 12, 21, 13.28)

Comment: Your desired output seems to be the result of averaging previous 6 non-na values with the same time. E.g. 13.28 ~ mean(c(21,14,2,12,12,22)). That does not match any interpretation of your description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to join the dataframe with itself on the conditions that two rows match if they are part of the group of rows that you want to find the average of.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[ , c("id", "dates_tmp1", "dates_tmp2", "dates_7", "time")
 := list(1:nrow(dt), dates, dates, dates - as.difftime(7, unit="days"), strftime(dates, format="%H:%M:%S"))]
```

Created some temporary columns for the join to not destroy the old data.

```
joined <- dt[dt, on=.(dates_tmp1>=dates_tmp1, dates_7<=dates_tmp2, time==time), allow=TRUE]
mean_values <- joined[ , list(mean_value=mean(i.value, na.rm = TRUE)), by = "id"]
mean_values <- mean_values[order(id)]
    id mean_value
 1:  1   20.00000
 2:  2    5.00000
 3:  3   10.00000
 4:  4   23.00000
 5:  5    5.00000
 6:  6   16.00000
```

Take these values to replace the NA ones.

If you want the last 7 days that occur in then you can create a new column that enumerates the days and then do the same.

```
dt[ , c("id",  "time"):= list(1:nrow(dt),strftime(dates, format="%H:%M:%S"))]
dt[ , days := as.numeric(frank(as.Date(dates), ties.method = "dense")), by = time]
dt[ , days_7:=days - 7]
joined <- dt[dt, on=.(days>=days, days_7<=days, time==time), allow=TRUE]
mean_values <- joined[ , list(mean_value=mean(i.value, na.rm = TRUE)), by = "id"]
```

Comment: Thanks mathdotrandom,Instead of calculating with in the week , if in  a week 2 days are missing then we will get only 5 days average ,instead of this can we consider for previous 7 days(not with in a week)?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the rows.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% as.data.table()
for(index in 1:nrow(df)){ # index <- 23
  print(index)
  if(df[index, value] %>% is.na()){
    if(index >= 7){
    df[index, value := df[(index - 7):(index-1), value] %>% mean()] 
    }else
    {
      df[index, value:=df[1:index-1, value] %>% mean()] 
    }
  }
}
```

I used `data.table` because I am more familiar with that. I guess you can continue with `data.frames` if you want after the processing.

tell me if this is whatyou want